# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase') in Next js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I creating web-app using Next JS framework and work on developing Search component. For this task I using the fragments of code from other project. I tested this project, and it works without errors. But in my project I get error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')" Here is the original code in /lib/posts.js
`

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import matter from 'gray-matter'
import remark from 'remark'
import html from 'remark-html'

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'posts')

export function getSortedPostsData() {
  // Get file names under /posts
  const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)
  const allPostsData = fileNames.map(fileName => {
    // Remove ".md" from file name to get id
    const id = fileName.replace(/\.md$/, '')

    // Read markdown file as string
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, fileName)
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8')

    // Use gray-matter to parse the post metadata section
    const matterResult = matter(fileContents)

    // Combine the data with the id
    return {
      id,
      ...matterResult.data
    }
  })
  // Sort posts by date
  return allPostsData.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.date < b.date) {
      return 1
    } else {
      return -1
    }
  })
```

`

Here is code in my project in /pages/api/search.js
`

```
import { getSortedPostsData } from '../../lib/posts'

const posts = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('../../cache/data').posts : getSortedPostsData()

export default (req, res) => {
  const results = req.query.q ?
    posts.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(req.query.q)) : []
  res.statusCode = 200
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ results }))
}
```

`
It inentic original code and was copy-pasted from the original source

And here is code of search component in /components/Search.js
`

```
import { useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from './search.module.css';

export default function Search() {

    const searchRef = useRef(null)
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
    const [results, setResults] = useState([])
  
    const searchEndpoint = (query) => `/api/search?q=${query}`
  
    const onChange = useCallback((event) => {
      const query = event.target.value;
      setQuery(query)
      if (query.length) {
        fetch(searchEndpoint(query))
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            setResults(res.results)
          })
      } else {
        setResults([])
      }
    }, [])
  
    const onFocus = useCallback(() => {
      setActive(true)
      window.addEventListener('click', onClick)
    }, [])
  
    const onClick = useCallback((event) => {
      if (searchRef.current && !searchRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setActive(false)
        window.removeEventListener('click', onClick)
      }
    }, [])
  
    return (
      <div
        className={styles.container}
        ref={searchRef}
      >
        <input
          className={styles.search}
          onChange={onChange}
          onFocus={onFocus}
          placeholder='Search posts'
          type='text'
          value={query}
        />
        { active && results.length > 0 && (
          <ul className={styles.results}>
            {results.map(({ id, title }) => (
              <li className={styles.result} key={id}>
                <Link href="/posts/[id]" as={`/posts/${id}`}>
                  <a>{title}</a>
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        ) }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

`And it is also have no differencec from original. But in my project after input in search box I get error`

```
error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/search.js:12:67)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/search.js:12:41)
    at Object.apiResolver (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:184:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async DevServer.runApi (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:403:9)
    at async Object.fn (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:493:37)
    at async Router.execute (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:222:36)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:612:29)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:569:20) {
  page: '/api/search'
}
   5 | export default (req, res) => {
   6 |   const results = req.query.q ?
>  7 |     posts.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(req.query.q)) : []
     |                                    ^
   8 |   res.statusCode = 200
   9 |   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  10 |   res.end(JSON.stringify({ results }))
event - compiled client and server successfully in 6.7s (581 modules)
wait  - compiling /api/search...
event - compiled successfully in 1697 ms (103 modules)
error - (api)/pages/api/search.js (7:56) @ eval
error - ReferenceError: props is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/search.js:12:87)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/search.js:12:41)
    at Object.apiResolver (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:184:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async DevServer.runApi (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:403:9)
    at async Object.fn (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:493:37)
    at async Router.execute (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:222:36)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:612:29)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/konstantin/Projects/next-linearjs-docs/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:569:20) {
  page: '/api/search'
}
   5 | export default (req, res) => {
   6 |   const results = req.query.q ?
>  7 |     posts.filter(post => props.post.title.toLowerCase().includes(req.query.q)) : []
     |                                                        ^
   8 |   res.statusCode = 200
   9 |   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  10 |   res.end(JSON.stringify({ results }))
```

`

What could be the reason for this?

I tried to find some random discrepancies in the code, but did not find them. Maybe someone else has experienced something similar and knows how to fix it.

Comment: What does your "cache" file look like?

Comment: It is cache file https://github.com/konvod93/nextjs-blog-search-api/blob/master/scripts/cache.js But in developing mode it don't works and works function getSortedPostData 
`const posts = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('../../cache/data').posts : getSortedPostsData()` 
I'm not running the application yet in production mode

Comment: Well, at least one `post` in your `posts` does not have a `title` Check your data ...   If you currently use the `getSortedPostsData()` add the following to your code after `// Combine the data with the id`:    `if (!matterResult.data.title) console.log(fileName)`  This will print all filenames, where the `title` is missing in the frontmatter

Comment: Thank You Very Much! Added title in post. Now application works!